# Google Tag Manager: Tracking Dynamic Button IDs on a Single Page Application (SPA)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, single-page-application, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

My e-commerce page is set-up as an **accordion-style**, **single page application** checkout page, and each step has a **"Next" button** that can be clicked to advance to the next step:

[image]

[image]

My goal is to set-up tracking within GTM to allow me to analyze drop-offs at each step. As a consequence of the page being configured as a **single page application (SPA)**, one way would be to track clicks on the "Next" button and call on the individual button ids as a trigger condition.

[image]

However, the button id (e.g. "uuid_1b8e49ce7175_button-triger-next...") is dynamic and changes upon refreshing the page.

[image]

What options are there available within GTM to track the completion of different stages of the checkout process and analyze the drop-offs at each stage?

Answer (score 1):

There's no 'universal' answer to this since each *'SPA application'* is supposed to have its own distinct layout so there might be several ways to track them with GTM.
One of the general approaches might be using 'ancestor' style CSS selector to point to specific 'Next' buttons.
Let's say your 'Next' buttons belong to some specific sections like:

```
<div class='quote'>
    ...
    <button id='jh23r4'>Next</button>
</div>
<div class='secelt_plan'>
    ...
    <button id='j23j98'>Next</button>
</div>
```

then you can referr the  first button as `.quote button` and the second button as `.secelt_plan button` using condition of *Click Element match CSS selector* in your GTM click trigger.

Consider checking docs on [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) for more details